# RegAsm VS RegSvc32 VS GAC

Tags: .net, registry

What is the difference between Regasm, RegSVC and GAC?

When someone is prefered over another?

Comment: Asking what they have in common would make for a much shorter answer.  Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 14):

- Regasm - part of the .NET framework which allows you to register .NET apps so COM clients can use it (COM Callable wrapper)
- regsvr - register unmanaged dll's (not .NET assemblies)
- gacutil - register .NET Assemblies in the GAC (global assemblies cache) so other .NET assemblies can reference them easily.